# Elegant way to check error is wrapped in Go

Tags: go, error-handling

We have one function that returns errors one of them is wrapped by `errors.Wrap()`, the others are not.

```golang
var ErrTest1 = errors.New("error test 1")
var ErrTest2 = errors.New("error test 2")
var ErrRPC = errors.New("error rpc")

func rpcCall() error {
    return ErrRPC
}

func testErrWrap(a int) error {
    if a == 1 {
        return ErrTest1
    } else if a == 2 {
        return ErrTest2
    } else {
        err := rpcCall()
        if err != nil {
            return errors.Wrap(ErrRPC, "call rpc err")
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

We have two solutions, one is

```golang
    err := testErrWrap(3)

    if errors.Unwrap(err) != nil {
        fmt.Println(errors.Unwrap(err))
    }
```

the other is

```golang
    err := testErrWrap(3)

    if !errors.Is(err, ErrTest2) && !errors.Is(err, ErrTest1) {
        tErr := errors.Unwrap(err)
        fmt.Println(tErr)
    }
```

We want to know the elegant way to distinguish errors are wrapped or not in Go?

Comment: `errors.Is` is more powerful than unwrapping manually, as it checks recursively. In the second example you can remove the manual unwrapping entirely. If you need the unwrapped error, use `errors.As`.

Comment: Why do you want to check that the error is wrapped? What problem are you solving?

Comment: @Flimzy, we want to filter the error `errors.Wrap(ErrRPC, "call rpc err")` from the return error of func `testErrWrap`, and then do some special logic for this error

Comment: Why does it matter that it's _wrapped_, though?  Why not just filter for that specific type of error, wrapped or not? This is more how errors are intended to be used.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use package variables as sentinel error values.  This is generally a bad idea. For one, they're mutable (which is dangerous!), second, they're not always easy to distinguish from each other (as you're noticing). There are better alternatives, which will probably also obviate your desire to detect wrapped errors.  One is to use [constants](https://dave.cheney.net/tag/errors), then `errors.Is` will work perfectly for you. Another is to use a custom error type which implements an interface, then `errors.Is` or `errors.As` will work for you, regardless of wrapping.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases we're looking to find out if we got a specific type of error in order to do some special logic to handle it. I'd argue there are better ways to do this than looking at whether the error was wrapped or not.

In this case I'd propose using custom error types and using `errors.Is` or `errors.As`

First let's create some code that has a custom error type:

```golang
type ErrRPC struct { 
   retryPort int
}

func (e ErrRPC) Error() string {
    return "Oh no, an rpc error!"
}

func testErrWrap(a int) error {
    switch a {
    case 1:
        return errors.New("errors test 1")
    case 2:
        return errors.New("errors test 1")
    default:
        err := rpcCall(9000)
        return fmt.Errorf("errors test: %w", err) // Wraps the ErrRPC
    }
}

func rpcCall(port int) error {
    return ErrRPC{retryPort: port + 1}
}
```

If we're only interested in going down a different code path when we get a specific error type I'd go with `errors.Is`

```golang
func main() {
    for i := 1; i <= 3; i++ {
        if err := testErrWrap(i); err != nil {
            if errors.Is(err, ErrRPC{}) {
                println("rpc error")
            } else {
                println("regular error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If we need to use a property of the error value for something, `errors.As` comes in handy.

```golang
func main() {
    for i := 1; i <= 3; i++ {
        if err := testErrWrap(i); err != nil {
            var rpcErr ErrRPC
            if errors.As(err, &rpcErr) {
                fmt.Printf("rpc error, retrying on port: %d", rpcErr.retryPort)
            } else {
                println("regular error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using `var rpcErr ErrRPC` assigning `err` value into it then using it to print it but let's say you want to process it further more, is it thread safe to process it further more?

Answer (score 0):

Another method from [puellanivis](https://github.com/pkg/errors/issues/243)

> Also consider testing for behavior:

```golang
err := testErrWrap(3)

var wrappedErr interface { Unwrap() error }
if errors.As(err, &wrappedErr) {
    fmt.Println(errors.Unwrap(err))
}
```

> But also of note, `errors.Wrap(…)` double wraps your error: one `WithMessage` and one `WithStack`. So using errors.Unwrap(err) on the error from `errors.Wrap(ErrRPC, "call rpc err")` will not give you ErrRPC.